# Scrolling text is flickering

Tags: html, css

I want to scroll a text from right to left and I am using css for that but text is flickering. Is there any other way to do the same so that text may not flicker? Please help.

HTML is

```
     <div class="scroll-left">
        <p>CSS scrolling text... </p>
    </div>
```

CSS is

```
.scroll-left{
margin-top: -130px;
font-size: 140px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.scroll-left p {
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);    
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
 }
 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    }
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   { 
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);        
    }
    100% { 
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: no it's not flickering. find demo https://jsfiddle.net/f5rp0ngq/

Comment: I tested the same code on different computer and it works fine. So i think its screen resolution issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same code on different computer and it works fine. So i think its screen resolution issue